# Android: ClassCastException ReInstallReceiver cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Please find my code below for my broadcast receiver

```
public class ReInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private String TAG =  "ReInstallReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null) {
        if(intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) {
            //do action
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Manifest entry :

```
<receiver android:name=".handleupgrade.ReInstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Error :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.packagename.handleupgrade.ReInstallReceiver cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have `import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;` in the `import`s at the top of your `ReInstallReceiver` class?

Comment: Hmm, you might try cleaning/rebuilding, especially if you recently changed that class. Also, your `if` conditional isn't right. Use the `String#equals()` method instead of `==`. (That's not the problem, atm, though, obviously.)

Answer (score 2):

This line in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".handleupgrade.ReInstallReceiver">
```

Means that your receiver is inside `handleupgrade` package. But your receiver is `com.packagename.ReInstallReceiver`.

Change the line in manifest to :

```
<receiver android:name="com.packagename.ReInstallReceiver">
```